# Check if voicechannel is empty? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hellou Guys!
I need to check if a voicechannel triggered by name is empty. so if yes, the bot have to delete the channel. Is there a Possible way to do a loop about every 10 seconds so the bot can check? Many thanks in advance for your efforts

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of you attempting this problem yourself. SO is not a code service website where we code for you. We will however help you with problems you face.

Comment: The [discordpy docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) also give all the answers you need for this.